# Yii2-codeception Missing submodules config on testing

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I'm trying to use codeception for functional testing, in my yii2-advanced-app (like described here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-testing.md)

The testing works fine with no dependencies, but when I add a sub module, like yii2-user (https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user), it doesn't seems to load the module bootstrap settings:

```
yii\base\InvalidParamException: Invalid path alias: @dektrium/user/views in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php:152
```

The module is declared in config/main.php

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
  'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
...
```

And loaded from config/test.php:

```
<?php
return yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
  require(__DIR__ . '/main.php'),
...
```

Am I forgetting something?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but I've had to temporarily comment the following line in my config/main.php out to move past this error:

```
'view' => [
        'theme' => [

            'pathMap' => [
              //  '@dektrium/user/views' => '@frontend/views/user'
            ],

        ],
```